# Bash one-liner to insert text marker into the fourth and all consecutive tabs of fields populated with text

Tags: perl, csv

This is a Bash/.bat terminal script for Mac.

I'm trying to add text ("!!XX!!") into a group of tab-delimited .txt files in a folder, but I only want to add it into the 4th and all following incidents of the tab in each .txt file, and then only if those cels have text in them. So, the end result would be something like (assuming the 7th cel/field/bit of info is blank). So turn this:

```
text01
text02
text03
text04
text05
text06
```

... into this:

```
text01 [TAB] text02 [TAB] text03 [TAB] text04!!XX!! [TAB] text05!!XX!! [TAB] text06!!XX!! [TAB]
```

The text marker "!!XX!!" is so that another script in a different system can run on the file and perform special system-compatible/custom line formatting at each incident of "!!XX!!", but I don't want to populate the first three fields/tab-delimited text (because it's not needed there) or in the empty fields (because it's not wanted there).

I'm already replacing each line return with a tab, so it is possible to do it there, though my preference is to do it later to the tab-delimited text b/c of weird issues with the line returns/formatting coming in from .rtf files. Below is what I am to replace each line return and replace it with a TAB (and, yes, that is an actual line return and tab in there, which seems to work best because... Macs?):

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/
/   /g' *.txt;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See [what to do when someone answers your question](/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Does each input txt file have exactly 7 lines? Or is it some-multiple-of-seven lines?

Comment: Your text and example do not match. Is it every 4th or starting on the 4th, every other one?

Comment: I take it that each line has tab-separated fields, where starting from (and including) the fourth one needs to add `!XX!` if there's anything in the field.  So it all happens on one line, for each line.  Please clarify since it is indeed unclear.

Comment: Each input .txt file does not have the same number of lines (it can range from 4 to 20+). It is the 4th+ so 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, etc. assuming that each has text; if not, I don't to add the text marker (So if the 8th is blank, the marker stops at 7th, otherwise I'd have a lot of text markers). I'm converting .rtf and .doc files to .txt, so that each individual doc becomes one, tab-delimited line (in a larger .txt doc to be imported into Excel).

Answer (score 4):

*This post assumes an input file that has lines with tab-separated fields, where each field starting from (and including) the fourth need be edited if it has something*.

---

One way

```
perl -F"\t" -wlane'
    for (3..$#F) { $F[$_] .= "!XX!" if defined $F[$_] }; print join("\t", @F)
' file
```

(In `tcsh` shell need to escape those `!` with a backslash.)  Once you've tested enough add `-i` switch to change input `file` in place (`-i.bak` keeps a backup).

This uses Perl's `-a` switch to break input lines by what is given under `-F` switch (or by whitespace by default), and the resulting array is in `@F`. See [switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches).

Then it iterates from the fourth field to the last. I use syntax `$#ary` for the index of the last element of array `@ary`.
I don't know what counts for cells that "*have text in them*" so above I test a field for `defined`-ness; thus this will append even for an empty string. Adjust as suitable.

Or use a regex, which  allows more flexibility here. For example,

```
for (3..$#F) {  $F[$_] =~ s/.+\K/!XX!/  }
```

This matches all characters and then adds `!XX!` (keeping what it matched, by [`\K` assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions)).  Using regex allows and demands to specify more precisely what is accepted there; the shown pattern will match even for whitespace alone, but not for empty string. To not touch fields with whitespace only, and to strip trailing spaces if any

```
for (3..$#F) { $F[$_] =~ s/.+\S\K\s*/XX/ };
```

Again, adjust to your details.

I don't quite understand the discussion of newlines and what is wanted of them; the above one-liner goes line by line. If that's not what you need please clarify. I don't have Macs to test, so I can't comment on all that.

A self-contained example for ready testing and tweaking

```
echo "t1\tt2\tt3\tt4\t\tt6 \t  " | 
perl -F"\t" -wlanE'for (3..$#F) { $F[$_] =~ /.+\S\K\s*/XX/ } say for @F'
```

where I print each field on a separate line for easier inspection. The last tab in input is followed by trailing spaces only -- this results in an empty field, but with no text marker added (as asked for in a comment).

Comment: This worked great - thanks! The only strangeness - which I did not really account for - is that there is a trailing text marker at the end. I might need to trim that, but I'll see. Thanks again!

Comment: @pjeigh OK, good to hear it works for you.  But ... what "trailing text marker", and at the end of what? (the whole line, or a field ...?)  If it's at the end of lines then perhaps there's an extra field (with just a space or newline or such) at the end of each line.  That'd be a bug and it better be fixed, not that you have to trim it separately---can you explain what it is?

Comment: @pjeigh Do you mean to say that your input has that to start with, or that after you use this code you end up with an extra `!XX!` at the end (of each line I presume)?

Comment: The latter - I end up with a trailing text marker at the end of the entire line. The text marker will be used to add a line return in another system, so there is not a need to have one at the end. I also just realized need to concatenate all of the text with the marker in it ... so that I'll end up with `code` text01[TAB] text02[TAB] text03[TAB] text04!!XX!!text05!!XX!!text06!!XXtext07 `code`

Comment: Is there a way to keep those first three tabs and either never insert the rest or to insert them all and then remove the all the tabs after the first three?

Comment: @pjeigh "_either never insert the rest or to insert them all and then remove the all the tabs after the first three_"  --- I don't understand -- just remove 4+ tabs? Sure. Never insert ... so to not change the line at all?

Comment: @pjeigh  What if a field has just whitespace -- do you want to add "text marker" or not?  I think that's what happens at the end of each line, you have an extra field (which you don't see in an editor because it's just space)

Comment: @pjeigh  Added another regex example to do some of what you mention, and changed the last one-liner --- adjust further to your liking.  The last one-liner should be convenient for tweaking and testing for various input

Comment: If the "field" is whitespace then no text marker is needed. I'll try the above soon... thanks! BTW: My temp. fix was to manipulate the final text file/data in Excel - I concatenate everything after the third tab - so it is all one line/cel - and then trim the trailing six chars ("!!XX!!"). (Side Note: via bash/.dat, I add a row of tabbed labels to me end text doc for  Excel labeling and made the last two "lables" Excel formulas, so I just drag down the cels for all the rows, then copy/paste the values into the 4th column ... but, of course, I'd prefer to have the script handle it).

Comment: @pjeigh  That would be the second regex above then, introduced with "_To not touch fields with whitespace only..._"

Answer (score 1):

with `GNU` sed

```
$ echo text{01..07}$'\t' | sed -E 's/([^\t]+)(\t|$)/\1!!xx!!/4g'

text01   text02  text03  text04!!xx!! text05!!xx!! text06!!xx!! text07!!xx!!
```

or

```
 $ echo text{01..07}$'\t' | sed -E 's/\t([^\t]+)/\1!!xx!!/3g'
```

Comment: MacOS does not ship with GNU sed by default, but it's simple to install it with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk:

```
echo text{01..10}$'\t' | 
awk -v OFS=$'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, i>=4 ? "XXX\t" : i<NF ? OFS : ORS }'
```

With perl, I would do this:

```
echo text{01..10}$'\t' | 
perl -lpE '$cnt=0; s/\h+/++$cnt>=4 ? "XXX\t" : "\t"/ge;'
```

Both print:

```
text01  text02  text03  text04XXX   text05XXX   text06XXX   text07XXX   text08XXX   text09XXX   text10XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each text file contains 7 lines, you can do

```sh
paste -s *.txt | awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    {for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") $i = $i "!!XX!!"; print}
'
```

Comment: Thanks - each .txt file can have any number of lines, from 4 on (realistic max is 40).

Comment: but each file represents a single row of the output data, right?